# how to run php files in linux Centos?

Tags: linux, centos, php

How can I get all my php files run in Apache? I copied all the php files to linux server under /www and I did change config setting like following. Also I did create error log file under /logs. But when I run mytest.example.com in browser, it is not working and the page showing that "Oops! Google Chrome could not find mytest.example.com". I think I may require to change or add something. Kindly assist me. Thanks in advance!

I use Putty to access the Centos and use WinSCP as FTP.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mytest.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/allphpfile/
ErrorLog logs/my_test_error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you actually use "mytest.example.com" or a real domain name? If you use a real domain name, did you check that DNS is resolving to the correct IP?

Comment: When I type "ping mytest.example.com</pre>",
it shows ping: unknown host mytest.example.com.
May I know what is that issue?

Comment: I'm not really using mytest.example.com. It is just an example link.

Comment: Could you show the output of # rpm -qa | grep php

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the php module is loaded with `LoadModule`, and add the following to your `VirtualHost`

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: There is no need to add anything by hand, all necessary settings are coming with php and located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

Answer (score 0):

> When I type "ping mytest.example.com", it shows ping: unknown
>   host mytest.example.com. May I know what is that issue?

This shows that your problem doesn't have anything to do with apache configuration, but with DNS resolution. mytest.example.com isn't resolved by your DNS.

Check your DNS configuration, make sure you have an A record set for your domain/subdomain and you did wait long enough for propagation. If your domain is using some provider's nameservers, contact the nameserver administration to get further help.